# View Model Items is Null after updating ItemsSource in User Control

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls, viewmodel

I'm working on a WPF MVVM application and running into an issue.  I'm familiar with WPF itself, however I've rarely used MVVM and I suspect I am doing something that MVVM doesn't support, however I don't know how else to accomplish what I am trying to do.

In the application, I have a user control called Agenda.  It consist several controls including a text box, a button to add a new agenda item, and a list box with a custom template.  The template includes an expander where the header is the agenda item title, up/down arrows to reorder items, and a button to delete the item.  The expander content contains a toolbar and a rich text box.  In the agenda UC I have a dependency property called `ItemsSource` which is an `IEnumerable<AgendaItem>`.

Now, I have a view called Appointment, its associated VM (AppointmentViewModel), and its model (AppointmentModel).  In the model, there is a field called AgendaItems which is an `ObservableCollection<AgendaItem>`.  The agenda UC is used within the appointment view and the UC's `ItemsSource` is bound to the `Model.AgendaItems` (the observable collection).

The problem I'm having is when I try to handle the buttons to reorder the agenda items in the UC.  As an example, for the button to move an agenda item up the list, this is the code in the UC:

```
var tb = sender as Button;
var tag = tb.Tag as AgendaItem;
var lst = ItemsSource.ToList();
var index = lst.IndexOf(tag);
if(index > 0)
{
    lst.RemoveAt(index);
    lst.Insert(index - 1, tag);
    ItemsSource = lst;
}
```

The tag of the up arrow is bound to the specific agenda item in the list so I know which item is being moved.  The problem comes after I update the `ItemsSource` property doing `ItemsSource = lst`.  After that line executes, the `AgendaItems` ObservableCollection in the VM is null.  The binding mode is set to `TwoWay`.

Since the the appointment UC is used in various windows in the application, it made sense to me that the reordering of agenda items should be taken care of my the UC instead of duplicating code in every window which makes use of the UC.  But updating the `ItemsSource` property in the UC results in the collection in the VM being null.

For reference, the `ItemsSource` property in the UC is defined as:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable<AgendaItem>), typeof(Agenda), new PropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnItemsSourceChanged)));
```

There is the regular .NET property:

```
public IEnumerable<AgendaItem> ItemsSource
{
    get => (IEnumerable<AgendaItem>)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty);
    set => SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);
}
```

And the `OnItemsSourceChanged` method is:

```
private static void OnItemsSourceChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (obj is Agenda control)
    {
        if (e.OldValue is INotifyCollectionChanged oldValueINotifyCollectionChanged)
        {
            oldValueINotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged -= control.ItemsSource_CollectionChanged;
        }
        
        if (e.NewValue is INotifyCollectionChanged newValueINotifyCollectionChanged)
        {
            newValueINotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged += control.ItemsSource_CollectionChanged;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help/guidance on how I can reorder the `ItemsSource` collection in the UC without breaking the VM would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: It should be obvious that a TwoWay Binding between an `ObservableCollection<AgendaItem>` and a `List<AgendaItem>` - which you get from `ItemsSource.ToList()` does not work. While you can assign an ObservableCollection to your ItemsSource property, you can not assign the List to the view model property. Not sure if it makes sense, but you could write `ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<AgendaItem>(lst);`

Comment: Besides that, in the `OnItemsSourceChanged` callback you should take care for handling the already present elements in `e.NewValue`. Do whatever you do in `ItemsSource_CollectionChanged` for all of them.

Comment: I did find (shortly after creating this post) that simply changing the data type of ItemsSource from IEnumerable<AgendaItem> to ObservableCollection<AgendaItem> resolved the issue.  Thank you for the suggestion anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By changing the data type of `ItemsSource` from `IEnumerable<AgendaItem>` to `ObservableCollection<AgendaItem>` resolved the issue.  Thank you to everyone who responded.  It is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since calling .ToList() on Enumerable creates new list and reassigning it to `ItemsSource` doesn't work, maybe define the `ItemsSourceProperty` as `IList<AgendaItem>` since this is the interface that you need to reorder the items.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(IList<AgendaItem>), typeof(Agenda), new PropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnItemsSourceChanged)));
```

(don't forget to change the signature of the `ItemsSource` property ).

You could also create list extension method to call it in your code like this:

```
ItemsSource.Move(ItemsSource.IndexOf(tag), MoveDirection.Up);
```

```
public static void Move<T>(this IList<T> list, int iIndexToMove,
    MoveDirection direction)
{
    if (list.Count > 0 && (direction == MoveDirection.Down && iIndexToMove < list.Count - 1)
                    || (direction == MoveDirection.Up && iIndexToMove > 0))
    {
        if (direction == MoveDirection.Up)
        {
            var old = list[iIndexToMove - 1];
            list[iIndexToMove - 1] = list[iIndexToMove];
            list[iIndexToMove] = old;
        }
        else
        {
            var old = list[iIndexToMove + 1];
            list[iIndexToMove + 1] = list[iIndexToMove];
            list[iIndexToMove] = old;
        }
    }
}


    public enum MoveDirection
    {
        Up,
        Down
    }
```

Comment: I had thought that by setting the the list (created with .ToList()) and re-assigning it back to ItemsSource would update the model through the 2-way binding.  However, by simply changing the type of ItemsSource from IEnumerable<AgendaItem> to ObservableCollection<AgendaItem> resolved the issue.  Thank you for the response though.